# Increase Spring Cloud Gateway RequestBodySize

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm currently getting a 413 Request Entity Too Large when posting something routing through a Spring Cloud Gateway. It works when the request body isn't larger than around 3MB.

Here is my application.yml (Scrubbed)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: my-awesome-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      routes:
        - id: my-service
          uri: https://myservicesdomainname
          predicates:
            - Path=/service/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
            - UserInfoFilter
            - name: Hystrix
              args:
                name: fallbackCommand
                fallbackUri: forward:/fallback/first
            - name: RequestSize
              args:
                maxSize: 500000000 #***** Here is my attempt to increase the size
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 10000
        response-timeout: 20000
```

This is the link I got RequestSize/args/maxSize from

```
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__gatewayfilter_factories.html#_requestsize_gatewayfilter_factory
```

Edit:
The issue was with a Kubernetes Ingress Controller. I fixed the issue there and it's now working

Comment: RequestSize is simply a filter that checks a header, not the actual size. version 2.1.0 is no longer supported. Can you try again with Hoxton.SR9 (gateway 2.2.6.RELEASE) or 2020.0.0 (gateway 3.0.0).

Comment: Does the 413 come from gateway or the downstream service?

Comment: I'm running springCloudVersion Hoxton.SR8. I'm fairly certain it is coming from the gateway as it's not getting sent through the filter, but I will verify that.

Comment: I successfully posted a 4MB and 10MB file thru gateway to httpbin.org

Comment: Would it change anything if the request body is JSON instead of a file?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything

Comment: I've verified it is for sure not making it into the gateway service.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't hitting the gateway at all, there was a kubernetes ingress redirecting to the gateway which returned the 413 Request Entity Too Large. Thanks for your help @spencergibb. It is now successfully going through the gateway

Comment: What was the issue @darthNater ? Kinda thinking im running into the same problem, but my ingress is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

it only compares Content-Length request header with specified limit, and rejects right away, i.e. it's not counting uploaded bytes